# asp.net overwriting files simultaneously

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, streamwriter

I have an asp.net website with a C# code-behind that, when processing, writes to a log file in the App_Data folder of the website, and also generates PDF files.  Using StreamWriter class.  Users prepare their data on one page, then hit a button which takes them to another page that does all of the data processing.  The data is passed over from the first page to the second using Session variables.

My issue is that when two users hit the button to process the data simultaneously, one of the users will eventually get a "Cannot write to a closed log file" error, and the other will process through normally.

Each file name is unique.  I have a database sequence number in the file name, so the files will never overlap.

What's strange is, data that is to be written in one file will appear in the other user's file, and it will be omitted from the proper user's file.

I don't know if this is a StreamWriter issue, an IIS issue, a session issue, or something else.

Comment: You implemented your own logging solution? Why? There's great logging libraries out there, such as [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) and [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/).

Comment: Maybe it is your very first time to meet such, but in computer science synchronization is something typical, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science) Existing libraries as suggested by @mason already take care of that, while if you insist to do your own logging, learn the locks and use them properly.